# DML trigger on a row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger "restrict_salary" which prohibits the awarding of a salary of more than 10,000 dollars to an employee who is neither president nor manager.
The trigger should not be triggered if an "update" does not affect the column "sal". After that was thinking of making the trigger to prohibit also an increase more than 9%. I have tried something but i'm stuck, here is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrict_salary
BEFORE
UPDATE OF sal
ON EMP
REFERENCING emp AS new_emp
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (sal > 10000)
BEGIN
DECLARE job VARCHAR2(30);
    select job into job from ename;
    IF job!='MANAGER' OR job != 'PRESIDENT' THEN
        raise_application_error (-20002, 'Cannot attribute more than 10000 dollars ');
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: do you get error messages? If so, please edit your question to include them. Good luck.

Comment: Remind me not to work for your company...they're cheapskates (or not based in California).

Comment: What about REFERENCING OLD AS old (for the old value of the salary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `begin` and `declare` the wrong way round. You have to declare your variables before you can begin the PL/SQL block.

I've also changed `before update of sal on emp` to `before update on emp` and added `new.` to the WHEN clause as this is required.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER restrict_salary
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.sal > 10000)
DECLARE 
   job ename.job%type;
BEGIN
    -- THERE WAS A MISSING WHERE CLAUSE!!!
   select job into job from ename where empid = :new.id;

   IF job not in ('MANAGER', 'PRESIDENT') THEN
      raise_application_error (-20002, 'Error that fit''s on page');
   END IF;

END restrict_salary;
/
```

The biggest problem is the missing WHERE clause for your `select into ...`. This means that you are always going to get the TOO_MANY_ROWS error if you have more than one row in this table. I've changed this, as you can see but you may have to change it again, depending on your schema.

In order to be clear I've added the name of the trigger to the `end` statement  and removed the unnecessary `referencing` clause. Both of these are unnecessary to make it work but help with readability.

Lastly, I've declared the variable `job` as a type of the column that you are getting it from. This enables you to change the column in the table and not affect the trigger at all. It's sensible to always declare variables that rely on tables like this as it greatly reduces the number of errors caused by changes in the database and massively reduces obfuscation in the code base.

I would highly recommend reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) to gain an understanding of the syntax.

Comment: thanks Ben, you have solved my problem. I really appreciate it.